# Как удалить все повторяющиеся слова в строке, введенной из клавиатуры

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.lang.String;


  class  Zapis {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a =  sc.nextLine();
        a = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a.split("-"))).toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "").replace(", ", "-");
        System.out.println( a);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто проходишься по всем словам в строке, и в новой, если их нет, добавляешь

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
foreach (String s : a){
  if (!words.contains(s))
    words.add(s);
}
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("");
foreach (String s : a){
  buffer.append(s + " ");
}
String a2 = buffer.toString();
```

ps. я мог ошибиться в наименованиях

Comment: обратите внимание на `HashSet`, гораздо более эффективная структура данных, чем это `buffer.indexOf(s)` или это `words.contains`